# Unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest>

Tags: android

I get for **each** of the `activities` declared in `AndroidManifest.xml the following compile error:

```
AAPT: error: unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest>.
```

It looks like `Android.Manifest.xml` doesn't like that it contains `activities` (I thought that was its main purpose ?!). The app (under construction for some weeks) never had this error. Here is the full code of `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.commonsense.android.doorway">


    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="Main Page"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".Stats"
        android:label="Stats Page" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Settings"
        android:label="Settings Page" />
    <activity
            android:name=".Help"
            android:label="Help Page" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Start"
        android:label="Start Page">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

     </activity>

     <activity
         android:name=".Eula"
         android:label="Eula Page" />

     <meta-data
         android:name="preloaded_fonts"
         android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />


    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

</manifest>
```

Please advise

Comment: You're missing the entire `<application>` element. Surely that didn't happen on its own.

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing. The cat must have walked over the keyboard. Added <application> and it runs now. Thx.